# SQL QUERY problem bookid

Tags: mysql

How do Find books (show their titles, authors and prices) that are on 'CIVIL WAR' (i.e., the title field contains 'CIVIL WAR'), available in 'AUDIO' format.

this is my schema
    * Books (bookid, title, author, year)
    * Customers (customerid, name, email)
    * Purchases (customerid, bookid, year)
    * Reviews (customerid, bookid, rating)
    * Pricing (bookid, format, price)

I did this but it did not work
SELECT  b.title, b.author, p.price
FROM BOOKS b,PRICING p INNER JOIN books ON p.bookid
WHERE b.title like '%CIVIL WAR%'  AND p.format like '%AUDIO%' 
group by p.format, p.price

Comment: Your question could use some formatting... put a blank line between paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks josh do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: Does the query you have give you errors? If not, what problems does it have?

Comment: Why the rollback from Jacob Relkins edit? He made your question a lot more readable and it was totally justified.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the ON clause is incomplete.

Try this:

```
SELECT b.title, b.author, p.price
FROM BOOKS b
INNER JOIN PRICING p ON p.bookid = b.bookid 
WHERE b.title like '%CIVIL WAR%' 
AND p.format like '%AUDIO%' group by p.format, p.price
```

See the = b.bookid at the end of the INNER JOIN? That's the issue.

Comment: thank you it works. I just changed to group by b.title and worked

Comment: You're welcome Sasha. Don't forget to select an answer for this question. And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @Sasha: You should mark this response as an "Accepted Answer" then.

Comment: # For each year, 'JOHN CHAMBERS' purchased at least one book, find the number of books purchased. That is, the output should be a set of tuples, each indicating a year and the number of books purchased by 'JOHN CHAMBERS' in that year.  here is what i have SELECT customerid, p.year
FROM PURCHASES p, BOOKS

Comment: You should create a new question for this on the main page. That way, everyone will see it and you'll get plenty of responses.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
 SELECT b.title, b.author, p.price 
 FROM BOOKS b
 INNER JOIN PRICING p ON p.bookid=b.bookid 
 WHERE b.title like '%CIVIL WAR%' AND p.format like '%AUDIO%' group by p.format, p.price
```